# java.lang.ClassFormatError: Field "XMLString" ... has illegal signature "V"

Tags: java, netbeans-8, glassfish-4

When I try to deploy my war file on Glassfish 4.0 I am getting following error and deployment is failing.

Please note that, Java version for Glassfish 4.0 and my Netbeans environment is same (jdk1.8.0_162).

Not sure why I am getting this error. Same is working with jdk1.7  versions with Glassfish 2.5 version when compiled and deployed. However we need to use JDK 1.8 and Glassfish 4.0 as part of our technology upgrade activities.

So please give me some insight and suggest some solutions to get rid of such errors.

**Root cause Stack Trace:**

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassFormatError: Field "XMLString" in class com/insuranceproduct/primary/country/ws/jaxws/ApplicationExceptionBean has illegal signature "V"
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:642)
... 75 more
```

**Full Stack Trace**

```
   javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at com.sun.xml.ws.model.Injector.inject(Injector.java:119)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.model.WrapperBeanGenerator.createExceptionBean(WrapperBeanGenerator.java:369)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.model.RuntimeModeler.getExceptionBeanClass(RuntimeModeler.java:400)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.model.RuntimeModeler.processExceptions(RuntimeModeler.java:1252)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.model.RuntimeModeler.processDocWrappedMethod(RuntimeModeler.java:968)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.model.RuntimeModeler.processMethod(RuntimeModeler.java:730)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.model.RuntimeModeler.processClass(RuntimeModeler.java:490)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.model.RuntimeModeler.buildRuntimeModel(RuntimeModeler.java:320)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.db.DatabindingImpl.<init>(DatabindingImpl.java:99)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.db.DatabindingProviderImpl.create(DatabindingProviderImpl.java:74)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.db.DatabindingProviderImpl.create(DatabindingProviderImpl.java:58)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.db.DatabindingFactoryImpl.createRuntime(DatabindingFactoryImpl.java:120)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.server.EndpointFactory.createSEIModel(EndpointFactory.java:521)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.server.EndpointFactory.create(EndpointFactory.java:300)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.server.EndpointFactory.createEndpoint(EndpointFactory.java:164)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.server.WSEndpoint.create(WSEndpoint.java:577)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.server.WSEndpoint.create(WSEndpoint.java:560)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.server.WSEndpoint.create(WSEndpoint.java:639)
        at org.glassfish.webservices.WSServletContextListener.registerEndpoint(WSServletContextListener.java:267)
        at org.glassfish.webservices.WSServletContextListener.contextInitialized(WSServletContextListener.java:104)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:5394)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.contextListenerStart(WebModule.java:743)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5932)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:691)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:1041)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:1024)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:747)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:2286)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1932)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:139)
        at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:122)
        at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:291)
        at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:352)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:500)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219)
        at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:491)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:539)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:535)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:534)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:565)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:557)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:556)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1464)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:109)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1846)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1722)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:534)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:224)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandlerBase.service(StaticHttpHandlerBase.java:189)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor80.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.model.Injector.inject(Injector.java:111)
        ... 71 more
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassFormatError: Field "XMLString" in class com/insuranceproduct/primary/country/ws/jaxws/ApplicationExceptionBean has illegal signature "V"
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:642)
        ... 75 more
```

Comment: What version of NetBeans8 are you using? Also, do not use Glassfish 4.0!!! Version **4.1.2** has been available for over a year and includes over a thousand bug fixes for the version you are using. Update your post if the problem persists when using the correct/latest version of Glassfish4. Also double check that your application really is built and run under JDK8u162 as stated.

Comment: To do that: select the node for your project, right click, select **Properties**, select **Sources** from the **Categories** panel and verify that the **Source/Binary Format** setting has a value of **JDK 8**. If not then correct the setting and rebuild.